# Type-C UFP source or sink

Tags: usb-device, usb-c, usb-pd

I'm very confused by USB power delivery. I've searched everywhere for the answer to my question and it just keeps getting me even more confused.

I have a microcontroller that plugs into my phone. Since the phone controls it and usually provides the power, it has pull-down resistors on the CC pins.

Now I want to add another USB port on the device so that if that one is powered, the phone will charge while using my device. If that second port has no power, the phone provides it to the device. This is a very simple and inexpensive device so I really don't want to have to put a controller on it. Is there really no simple way to optionally provide external power?